# How to perform a conversion based on a given value using dax

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax

I'm trying to create a conversion based on distinct column values(emails) divided by number of transactions(clients) carried out.

I've tried pointing out a formula to count email in the column.

```
emailConversionRate = 
  DIVIDE ( 
   DISTINCTCOUNT ( 
    ClientTransView[TransEntityID]
 ), 
   Count( Interactions[chaneltype='email'
  )
)
```

I expect the output to be the number of entity IDs divided by the channel type used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `CALCULATE` function for filtering the `chaneltype` and use double quotes for email as it must be a string.

```
emailConversionRate =
    DIVIDE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( ClientTransView[TransEntityID] ),
        CALCULATE (
            COUNT ( Interactions[chaneltype] ),
            Interactions[chaneltype] = "email"
        )
    )
```